# How to subclass ABCMeta

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, metaclass

Normally, to subclass a class I do something like

```
class Subby(Parenty):
    def __init__(self):
        Parenty.__init__(self)
```

But now I'm trying to subclass a metaclass, specifically ABCMeta, so I'm doing

```
import ABCMeta

class Subby(ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
       ABCMeta.__init__(self) #this never seems to run

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace):
        cls = ABCMeta.__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
        return cls
```

But, when I then try to subclass `Subby` as a metaclass like

```
class newClass(metaclass=Subby):
    pass
```

I get the error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given`.

Why is this, and how do I subclass ABCMeta correctly?

Comment: `__init__` needs to take the same arguments `__new__` does.

Comment: Can you instantiate `Subby` on its own?

Comment: `ABCMeta` is the `abc.ABCMeta` class or another one defined in another module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the datamodel:

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.

So, as @user2357112 said, *the signatures must match*.

Despite this, there's really no reason to define `__init__` and `__new__` if you simply want to create an ABC. Just create it and use `.register` to register the conforming classes. Optionally, create a number of abstract methods and a `__subclasshook__` that checks for conformance. A good example already exists in the [`abc` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#module-abc).

Comment: For cheer coincidence, I've just written an answer where I actually _did_ subclass ABCMeta, for a purpose. (I had not seen this question before). I may be a nice example for this question  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43884960/108205