# Avoid inheriting generated class attributes using metaclass

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

I was thinking of automatically adding child classes to parent for "chaining" using a metaclass. However, inheriting these attributes from parent classes messes thing up. Is there a nice way to avoid this?

```
class MetaError(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for base in bases:
            setattr(base, name, cls)
        super(MetaError, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class BaseError(Exception, object):

    def __init__(self, message):
        super(BaseError, self).__init__(message)

class HttpError(BaseError):
    __metaclass__ = MetaError

class HttpBadRequest(HttpError):
    pass

class HttpNotFound(HttpError):
    pass

class FileNotFound(HttpNotFound):
    pass

class InvalidJson(HttpBadRequest):
    pass

http = HttpError

#  now I can do
raise http.HttpNotFound('Not found')
raise http.HttpNotFound.FileNotFound('File not found')
raise http.HttpBadRequest.InvalidJson('Invalid json')

#  unfortunately this also works
raise http.HttpBadRequest.HttpBadRequest('Bad request')
raise http.HttpBadRequest.HttpNotFound('Not found')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this turns out to be trickier than it seens at first - 
because basically you want to have class inheritance relationship, but do not use the normal attribute lookup paths on class inheritance - 
Otherwise, HTTPError, being a subclass of BaseError, for example, would always have all the attributs present in BaseError itself - Therefore,
the chain `BaseError.HTTPError.HTTPError.HTTPError.HTTPError...` would always be valid.

Fortunately, Python does *offer*  a mechanism to register classes as subclasses of other, without "physical" inheritance - that is, it is reported as subclass, but does not have the parent class in its bases or `__mro__` - and therefore, attribute lookup on the derived class (adopted?) does not search attributes in the "foster" parent.

This mechanism is provided through the "[abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)" or "abc"s, through its ABCMeta Metaclass, and "register" method.

And now, due to the fact you also probably want to declare
your class hierarchy with the normal inheritance syntax - that is,
being able to write `class HTTPError(BaseError):` to indicate the new
class derives from BaseError - you get the actual "physical" inheritance.

So, we can inherit from ABCMeta class (instead of `type`) and write 
the `__new__` method so that the physical inheritance is excluded - 
and we use the `setattr` for containment you intended with your code as well, and also, we trigger the needed call to `parentclass.register` directly on the metaclass.

(Note that as we are now changing the base classes, we need to fiddle 
in the `__new__` method of the metaclass, not on `__init__`:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class MetaError(ABCMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):

        new_bases = []
        base_iter = list(reversed(bases))
        seen = []
        register_this = None
        while base_iter:
            base = base_iter.pop(0)
            if base in seen:
                continue
            seen.append(base)
            if isinstance(base, MetaError):
                register_this = base
                base_iter = list(reversed(base.__mro__))  + base_iter
            else:
                new_bases.insert(0, base)
        cls = super(MetaError, metacls).__new__(metacls, name, tuple(new_bases), attrs)
        if register_this:
            setattr(register_this, name, cls)
            register_this.register(cls)
        return cls
```

And for a quick test:

```
class BaseError(Exception):
    __metaclass__ = MetaError
class HTTPError(BaseError):
    pass
class HTTPBadRequest(HTTPError):
    pass
```

In the interactive mode, check if it works as you intend:

```
In [38]: BaseError.HTTPError
Out[38]: __main__.HTTPError

In [39]: BaseError.HTTPError.HTTPError
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-5d5d03751646> in <module>()
----> 1 BaseError.HTTPError.HTTPError

AttributeError: type object 'HTTPError' has no attribute 'HTTPError'

In [40]: HTTPError.__mro__
Out[40]: (__main__.HTTPError, Exception, BaseException, object)

In [41]: issubclass(HTTPError, BaseError)
Out[41]: True

In [42]: issubclass(HTTPBadRequest, BaseError)
Out[42]: True

In [43]: BaseError.HTTPError.HTTPBadRequest
Out[43]: __main__.HTTPBadRequest

In [44]: BaseError.HTTPBadRequest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-b40d65ca66c6> in <module>()
----> 1 BaseError.HTTPBadRequest

AttributeError: type object 'BaseError' has no attribute 'HTTPBadRequest'
```

And then, most important of all, testing if the Exception hierarchy actually works in this way:

```
In [45]: try:
   ....:     raise HTTPError
   ....: except BaseError:
   ....:     print("it works")
   ....: except HTTPError:
   ....:     print("not so much")
   ....: 
it works
```

A few notes:  no need to inherit from both `Exception` and `object` explicitly - `Exception` itself already inherits from `object`. And, most important: whatever project you are working on, do whatever is possible to move it to Python 3.x instead of Python 2. Python 2 is with the days counted, and there are many, many new features in Python 3 you are excluding yourself of using. (The code in this answer is Python 2/3 compatible, but for the `__metaclass__` usage declaration of course).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may well be the best road to take (alternatively it seems that a global mapping based solution would also work - posted as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

A fairly naive global mapping solution that also seems to be working:

```
m = {}
class MetaError(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for base in bases:
            m[(base, name)] = cls 
        super(MetaError, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

    def __getattribute__(self, value):
        if (self, value) in m:
            return m[self, value]
        return type.__getattribute__(self, value)

class BaseError(Exception):
    __metaclass__ = MetaError

class HttpError(BaseError):
    pass

class HttpBadRequest(HttpError):
    pass

class HttpNotFound(HttpError):
    pass

class FileNotFound(HttpNotFound):
    pass

class InvalidJson(HttpBadRequest):
    pass
```